# Ассоциативный массив fetchAll()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

Имеется функция возвращающая ассоциативный массив:

```
public function getSports(): array
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id, name FROM Sport';
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
```

Но кроме полей `id` и `name` приходят ещё `0` и `1`. Как оставить только `id` и `name`?

P.s. документацию читал, вроде в `fetchAll()` нужно передать константы, но не нашёл какие.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php

FETCH_ASSOC: возвращает массив, индексированный именами столбцов результирующего набора